# How to Move the Solution explorer in Visual Studio 2019 to the left? (and the other stuff)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, window-management

I am having a hard time to move all the stuff under the solution explorer in Visual Studio 2019 to the left.
If it do it manually, stuff will open in the Tab. the Left, Top and Right option for the tabs is not available like for any cpp files open.
Any searching in the documentation simply ends in not solving my question/problem.

This drives me crazy.

Comment: Are you referring to Visual Studio 2019 instead of Visual Studio Code? They are very different software

Comment: Yes i am, i will edit it.